# stats for srtsrc element is sending a message without any data

Tags: c++, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0, qtgstreamer, java-gstreamer

Need to get  and print stat from srtsrc element from gstreamer 1.22 version. recent version uses this code

```
GstStructure *stats;
g_object_get(source, "stats", &stats, NULL);
gchar *stats_str = gst_structure_to_string(stats);
std::cout  << (stats_str ? stats_str : "null") << std::endl;
```

and receiving this result. Just this result, nothing more. Even when you stream to the source element nothing is changed.

```
application/x-srt-statistics, bytes-received-total=(guint64)0;
```

As far as documentation says [in this issue in Gstreamer-java repo](https://github.com/gstreamer-java/gst1-java-core/issues/173)    srt can provide more information like msRTT or bandwidth rate.
How can we get the stats in C++?

pipeline for reference is below:
[image: pipeline for reference]

Comment: Did you have any success setting up a pipeline using **gst-launch-1.0** to achieve that? Were you able to get the data you are expecting? What does that pipeline look like?

Comment: @karlphillip Pipeline is working okay. I am using C++ dynamic construction. Data is Okay but cant get the stats. As I show the plugin it is on srtobject.h but don't know how to invoke it from srtsrc and srtsink.